# phpMyAdmin never loading or giving 502 Bad Gateway errors

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use infinityfree, alright? So I need the apps installed on my site as security doesn't really like IP address sites. So I went to the Softilicious installer and found phpMyAdmin. I thought this was perfect. So I install it on my subdomain (phpmyadmin.site.com), and go to it.
I login to it with the correct details... but. It never loads, or gives a 502 Bad Gateway error. I've reinstalled it to be sure, I've checked my internet, nothing's wrong. I checked the server (my sql server), and it's fine. After about 10 minutes it loads. That's way too long. Has anyone else had this issue and has been able to fix it?

Comment: check the state of httpd and mysqld services

Comment: https and mysqli? i don't know what httpd and mysqlt is if you are saying to check those, cause I also don't have access to that if so.

Comment: @Ayoub Benayache alright, nevermind. The servers are fine.

Comment: This still isn't working??? I'm not sure what's going on with it. The servers are fine, and my hosting server is fine. Nothing